# make Preview in Preference Bundles

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak

Can I preview for user by selecting each theme?

I set 4 images for each option .. And so the user can see a preview of the subject evaluation before Respring

For example:

I want the image to be displayed only in the "Pixel Green" selection

Is it possible?

It's out of a tweak for a Jailbreak device

Within PreferenceBundles

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of [Add a preview to the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56210293/add-a-preview-to-the-user)

Comment: You already posted this question yesterday. Please do not post the same question again to "bump" it. If you have new information, you can edit your original question.